# Roofs not appearing in Unity

Tags: unity, 3d, models, blender

My buildings are fine until I import them to Unity. None of the formats I've come across( FBX, DAE, 3DS Max, Blender Files, any of the Autocad formats, OBJ, PRJ, WRL etc.), have roofs when importing the buildings as one cohesive file into Unity. In Sketchup, Blender etc. they all appear fine. Does anyone have suggestions?

[image: My buildings as they appear in Unity]

[image: Buildings with ceilings in Blender]

Comment: So I've inverted the normals and sure enough got the opposite result. Is there a way to merge these two formations in question to form whole blocks?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of your problem is with the way your 'normals' are facing in your 3D-modeling program.  If you are using Blender, you can select your faces, press w, and select 'flip normals'. It should turn your darker colored faces to a normal lighter color again.

Comment: So I've inverted the normals and sure enough got the opposite result. Is there a way to merge these two formations in question to form whole blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Your roof planers have inverted normals. Try to invert normals of roofs in your model-making software then reimport them in Unity

Comment: So I've inverted the normals and sure enough got the opposite result. Is there a way to merge these two formations in question to form whole blocks? Thanks for the help by the way